# Unable to install Scikit-Learn via pip on Mac with Python 3.7

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, python-3.7

I'm trying to install scikit-learn on my machine (macOS 10.13.4, Python 3.7.0) to no avail.

I've tried the following:

- Reinstalling all of the dependancies
- Clearing the cache and redownloading
- Force reinstalling the dependancies
- Installing via the PyCharm GUI as opposed to at the command line via pip3
- Running pip from within the python command line
- Repeating the steps with Python 3.6.4

None of those steps have been successful; instead, I receive the following error after running the install command.

```
my_computer_hostname:~ my_user_folder$ pip3 install -U --force-reinstall scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/2c/5edf2488897cad4fb8c4ace86369833552615bf264460ae4ef6e1f258982/scikit-learn-0.19.1.tar.gz

Installing collected packages: scikit-learn

  Running setup.py install for scikit-learn ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/hs/tvsnk51x3y925ntsyl3rbh2w0000gn/T/pip-install-x7yzme__/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/hs/tvsnk51x3y925ntsyl3rbh2w0000gn/T/pip-record-lorv9be_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:

    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries blis not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      FOUND:
        extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
        extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building library "libsvm-skl" sources
    building extension "sklearn.__check_build._check_build" sources
    building extension "sklearn.cluster._dbscan_inner" sources

    … (Abridged for StackOverflow Char Limit) …

    building extension "sklearn.utils._logistic_sigmoid" sources
    building data_files sources
    build_src: building npy-pkg config files
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn
    copying sklearn/learning_curve.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn
    copying sklearn/multiclass.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn

    … (Abridged for StackOverflow Char Limit) …

    copying sklearn/tests/test_kernel_approximation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/tests
    running build_clib
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler using build_clib
    building 'libsvm-skl' library
    compiling C++ sources
    C compiler: g++ -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/svm
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/svm/src
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm
    compile options: '-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c'
    g++: sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp
    ar: adding 1 object files to build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/liblibsvm-skl.a
    ranlib:@ build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/liblibsvm-skl.a
    running build_ext
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
    building 'sklearn.__check_build._check_build' extension
    compiling C sources
    C compiler: gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/__check_build
    compile options: '-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c'
    gcc: sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.c
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7 -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    building 'sklearn.cluster._dbscan_inner' extension
    compiling C++ sources
    C compiler: g++ -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g

    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/cluster
    compile options: '-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c'
    g++: sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp
    In file included from sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:514:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1816:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
    #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
     ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5960:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        *type = tstate->exc_type;
                ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5961:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        *value = tstate->exc_value;
                         ^~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5962:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5969:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                   ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5970:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
                            curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5971:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5972:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        tstate->exc_type = type;
        ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5973:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        tstate->exc_value = value;
                ^~~~~~~~~
                curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5974:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6029:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                   ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6030:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
                            curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6031:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6032:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        tstate->exc_type = local_type;
        ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6033:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        tstate->exc_value = local_value;
                ^~~~~~~~~
                curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6034:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    1 warning and 15 errors generated.
    In file included from sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:514:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18:
    In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1816:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
    #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
     ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5960:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        *type = tstate->exc_type;
                ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5961:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        *value = tstate->exc_value;
                         ^~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5962:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5969:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                   ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5970:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
                            curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5971:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5972:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        tstate->exc_type = type;
        ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5973:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        tstate->exc_value = value;
                ^~~~~~~~~
                curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:5974:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        tstate->exc_traceback = tb;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6029:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                   ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6030:25: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
                            curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6031:22: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        tmp_tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6032:13: error: no member named 'exc_type' in '_ts'
        tstate->exc_type = local_type;
        ~~~~~~  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6033:13: error: no member named 'exc_value' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        tstate->exc_value = local_value;
                ^~~~~~~~~
                curexc_value
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:237:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp:6034:13: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in '_ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                curexc_traceback
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pystate.h:238:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    1 warning and 15 errors generated.
    error: Command "g++ -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/sklearn/cluster/_dbscan_inner.o.d" failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/hs/tvsnk51x3y925ntsyl3rbh2w0000gn/T/pip-install-x7yzme__/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/hs/tvsnk51x3y925ntsyl3rbh2w0000gn/T/pip-record-lorv9be_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hs/tvsnk51x3y925ntsyl3rbh2w0000gn/T/pip-install-x7yzme__/scikit-learn/
```

From what I can tell, it seems as though I'm missing an additional dependency; any ideas as to what that might be or other suggestions such that I can install?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Current scikit-learn stable release (0.19.1) does not support Python 3.7. There are open issues in scikit-learn GitHub.  You shouldn't have any problems with Python 3.6.x.

Comment: Thank you! Realized I wasn't forcing the install with Python 3.6 in pip; that's why it wasn't working there. It's now installed; thanks again!